# Visual Fox Pro 9 Setting up the envoirment / Scanning for SMB2

Tags: networking, visual-foxpro

The Question:

Is there an easy way to check the Network if someone uses the SMB2 Protocol and Locks Files?

Background:

Hi,

I'm Programming an Aplication with VFP9.

We have many customers but one has a problem with performance.

Sometimes the speed of the Application comes to a hold. The description of the User comes very close to the Problem from "SMB2 Visual Foxpro and Windows SBS Edition".

The IT Person of our customer said he deactivated the SMB2 Protocoll on all Clients and Servers but still this problem comes up.

Comment: Did you also have the network guy turn off Opportunistic Locking?

Comment: I thought Opportunistic Locking is deactivated with SMB2. I will look further into it.